# arrays and if statements and accessing each index position

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I am not sure I understand if statements and how they access arrays as well as I would like. I have this array:

If I `var_dump($count)` I get:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#2472 (1) { ["nmbr_tables"]=> string(1) "4" } } array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#2445 (1) { ["nmbr_tables"]=> string(1) "0" } } array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#2452 (1) { ["nmbr_tables"]=> string(1) "0" } }
```

So I write

```
if($count >= 1){echo "hello";} else {echo "no";};
```

my expected output would be:

```
hello
no
no
```

Since the first index position has the nmbr "4" and then the next two have the nmbr "0"

Instead what I am getting is:

```
hellohellohello
```

Seeming to indicate that it is only paying attention to the first index position.

So then I thought maybe:

```
   foreach($count  as $val){
   if($count >= 2){echo "hello";} else {echo "no";};
   };
```

No difference.

If I var_export($count) I get:

```
array ( 0 => (object) array( 'nmbr' => '4', ), )array ( 0 => (object) array( 'nmbr' => '0', ), )array ( 0 => (object) array( 'nmbr' => '0', ), )
```

Comment: `$count` is your array in the `foreach`. You need to look at `$val`. First context is unclear, a static call would only output 1 value, not 3.

Comment: Thanks I get "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int "  when using a foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Quick Solution

It looks as though your input array `$count` is in the format:

```
$count = [ (object) [ 'nmbr' => '0', ] ];
```

So your conditional should be formatted as:

```
echo ($count[0]->nmbr >= 1) ? "hello" : "no", PHP_EOL;

// You want the first [0] item in the subarray of `$count` and you then want to access the property "nmbr"
```

---

### How it works

#### Ternary Logic

The echo in the above statement uses a shorthand `if` statement with the ternary operator. The general form of which is:

```
CONDITION ? TRUE : FALSE;

// You can use parentheses or not...
//   Whatever makes it easiest to read and understand;
//   all of these (and the one above) are the same

( CONDITION ) ? ( TRUE ) : ( FALSE );
( CONDITION ) ? ( TRUE ) : FALSE;
( CONDITION ) ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

and is equivalent to:

```
if(CONDITION){
    //Do something if TRUE
}
else{
   //Do something if FALSE
}
```

In this the ternary logic is evaluated and the result is returned to the `echo` which then outputs the string...

```
echo $count[0]->nmbr >= 1 ? "hello" : "no";
```

Note for each iteration of your larger loop `$count` looks like

```
$count = [ (object) [ 'nmbr' => '0', ] ];

// Therefore...

$count[0] == (object) [ 'nmbr' => '0', ];

// and finally...

$count[0]->nmbr == 0;
```

#### Running code on `true`

There are a few ways you can do this:

1. Use a function as the true/false condition

   - Note: you can't use `echo` *inside* a ternary
2. Change back to a standard `if`

So, for example you could do either of the below:

```
if($count[0]->nmbr >= 1){
    // Code to carry out if true
    echo "This is true!";
}
else{
    // Code to carry out if false
    echo "false logic :(";
}
```

OR...

```
function countIsMoreThanOne() : void
{
    // Code to carry out if true
    echo "This is true!";
}

$count[0]->nmbr >= 1 ? countIsMoreThanOne() : "false logic :(";
```

OR...

```
$count[0]->nmbr >= 1 ? print("This is true!") : "false logic :(";
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this and I am getting the error - "Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: @user15081222 Then it sounds like your `$count` is at a deeper level than I've guessed at. Can you copy/paste the output of `var_export($count)`?

Comment: Thank you. sorry I didnt clarify, that `$count =` was actually the var_dump of $count

Comment: It doesn't seem to be complete? There should be an all encompassing array (`array(3)`) which doesn't appear to be shown? `var_export` mean we can cop/y paste and use the code directly

Comment: Think I misread that. l I added `var_export` instead of `var_dump`

Comment: Okay, next question, is `$count` part of a wider loop? It looks to me as though the `var_*` calls are being called three times not the one time I had expected?

Comment: Yes it is inside of another loop that it is pulling data from. I was trying to keep the question simple, seems as if it might have had the opposite effect?

Comment: @user15081222 Possibly! I've updated the answer. Try replacing the `for` loop with the above `echo`. Hopefully that works

Comment: ok so that works. :) Now the follow up is if I want to replace "hello" and "no" with actual additional code, how do I do that based on the code in your answer? (The hello and no were place holders for me in order to take my learning step by step). The idea is that for for each if the value is great than or equal to "1" for each then it executes some code, if not then it says "none" or the like

Comment: @user15081222 One moment I'll update and explain

Comment: so much apprecaited

Comment: @user15081222 hopefully that clears things up?

Comment: This is a great and detailed answer. Thanks again for going above and beyond in helping me and posting a great answer for the community

Comment: @user15081222 no problem at all, good luck with the learning process!

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
foreach($count as $val){

    if($val >= 2){
        echo "hello";
    }
    else{
        echo "no";
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks I get "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int "

Comment: What do you get if you make a var_dump($val); die(); ?

Comment: The OP would get `(object) array( 'nmbr' => '4', )`. If you changed it to `$val->nmbr` it would work **and** it would also work if you took the loop out and made the condition `$count[0]->nmbr >= 2`. _See the `var_export` added to the question for clarification_